# Combine Pulsar and Python into docker-compose.yaml

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, apache-pulsar

**Background**:

I've setup up a [standalone Pulsar](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/standalone/) locally and used Pulsar's [python api docs](https://pulsar.apache.org/api/python/2.8.0-SNAPSHOT/) to execute a simple consumer and producer modules.

**Problem:**

Transfer basic workflow into docker-compose.yaml

1. Setup up [standalone Pulsar](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/standalone/) locally.
2. Install requirements.txt with needed for `consumer.py` and `producer.py` modules
3. Run `consumer.py`
4. Run `producer.py`

**What I've done so far:**

I've figured out how to compose the Pulsar standalone with the following yaml configuration

**Current pulsar image:**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  standalone:
    image: apachepulsar/pulsar:2.8.1
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 6650:6650
    command: bin/pulsar standalone
```

**Where I'm lost**

But I'm struggling conceptually with how I add Python 3.8 and the requirements need in the API docs to then be able to run the python commands `python consumer.py` and `python producer.py`

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need another image. You should keep your code running locally and point it at pulsar image.

If you really wanted to run a python docker image, you could do something like this, where `example_default` is a network name created by compose...

```
docker run --network=example_default -v /path/to/code:/app python:3 /app/producer.py
```

You will also need to modify your code to not use `localhost` as the Pulsar server address